# How can I flatten dict containing list by considering its index as key?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x, flatten

I want to flatten the dict. Dictionary may contain lists. So while flattening lists inside dictionary, it should consider list index as its key.

How can I do the same?

I tried:

```
def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep='__'):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)
```

This is flattening dict but ignoring lists.

I also tried to add `if isinstance(v, list):`, but I am not getting how to `append` / `extend` in `items`.

```
data = {
    "checksum": "c540fcd985bf88c87e48c2bfa1df5498",
    "data": {
        "sampleMetrics": {
            "name": "DNA Library QC Metrics",
            "passQualityControl": "true",
            "metrics": [{
                "name": "CONTAMINATION_SCORE",
                "value": 1302,
                "LSL": 0,
                "USL": 3106,
                "UOM": "NA"
            }]
        }
    }
}
print flatten(data)
```

**Output I am getting:**

```
{
    'checksum': 'c540fcd985bf88c87e48c2bfa1df5498',
    'data__sampleMetrics__metrics': [{
        'LSL': 0,
        'USL': 3106,
        'name': 'CONTAMINATION_SCORE',
        'value': 1302,
        'UOM': 'NA'
    },{ 'demo': 11}],
    'data__sampleMetrics__name': 'DNA Library QC Metrics',
    'data__sampleMetrics__passQualityControl': 'true'
}
```

Which is flattening other thing except list elements.

**Expected output :** It should flatten list as well.(By considering list index as key.)

```
{
    'checksum': 'c540fcd985bf88c87e48c2bfa1df5498',
    'data__sampleMetrics__metrics__0__LSL': 0,
    'data__sampleMetrics__metrics__0__USL': 3106,
    'data__sampleMetrics__metrics__0__name': 'CONTAMINATION_SCORE',
    'data__sampleMetrics__metrics__0__value': 1302,
    'data__sampleMetrics__metrics__0__UOM': 'NA',
    'data__sampleMetrics__metrics__1__demo': 11,
    'data__sampleMetrics__name': 'DNA Library QC Metrics',
    'data__sampleMetrics__passQualityControl': 'true'
}
```

**How can I flatten dict containing list by considering its index as key?**

Comment: @PatrickArtner added expected output

Comment: @DirtyBit : Added expected output

Comment: It's in double quote. Modified the same

Comment: If the index is the key, then shouldn't those all be `0__LSL`, `0__USL`, `0__name`, etc., since that nested dict is the 0th element of the list?

Comment: @muru .. yes.. correct .. modifying the question.

Comment: What should happen if there's more than one dict in the `"metrics"` list?

Comment: @martineau it should be flatten too. 2nd element will be considered as 1st index and 3rd will be considered as 2nd index and so on. I have modified question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check for lists as well - they are not [MutableMapings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) - hence they currently fall under your `else:` part and get added as is:

```
import collections
from itertools import chain 

def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep='__'):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for idx, value in enumerate(v):
                items.extend(flatten(value, new_key + sep + str(idx), sep).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)

data = {
    "checksum": "c540fcd985bf88c87e48c2bfa1df5498",
    "data": {
        "sampleMetrics": {
            "name": "DNA Library QC Metrics",
            "passQualityControl": "true",
            "metrics": [{
                "name": "CONTAMINATION_SCORE",
                "value": 1302,
                "LSL": 0,
                "USL": 3106,
                "UOM": "NA"
            },{ 'demo': 11}]
        }
    }
}

print flatten(data)
```

Output:

```
{'data__sampleMetrics__metrics__0__LSL': 0, 
 'checksum': 'c540fcd985bf88c87e48c2bfa1df5498', 
 'data__sampleMetrics__metrics__0__name': 'CONTAMINATION_SCORE', 
 'data__sampleMetrics__metrics__1__demo': 11, 
 'data__sampleMetrics__metrics__0__UOM': 'NA', 
 'data__sampleMetrics__metrics__0__USL': 3106, 
 'data__sampleMetrics__metrics__0__value': 1302, 
 'data__sampleMetrics__passQualityControl': 'true', 
 'data__sampleMetrics__name': 'DNA Library QC Metrics'}
```

---

To get a "sorted" output you would need to use an OrderedDict in python 2.x:

from collections import OrderedDict

```
data = OrderedDict(sorted(flatten(data).items()))
print data
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('checksum', 'c540fcd985bf88c87e48c2bfa1df5498'), 
             ('data__sampleMetrics__metrics__0__LSL', 0), 
             ('data__sampleMetrics__metrics__0__UOM', 'NA'), 
             ('data__sampleMetrics__metrics__0__USL', 3106), 
             ('data__sampleMetrics__metrics__0__name', 'CONTAMINATION_SCORE'), 
             ('data__sampleMetrics__metrics__0__value', 1302), 
             ('data__sampleMetrics__metrics__1__demo', 11), 
             ('data__sampleMetrics__name', 'DNA Library QC Metrics'), 
             ('data__sampleMetrics__passQualityControl', 'true')])
```

Comment: For python3 you have to replace `collections.MutableMapping` with `collections.abc.MutableMapping` to avoid getting a warning. Import MutableMapping from collections directly is not supported anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Since a list isn't a mapping, but a sequence, you would need to add a case for it:

```
if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
    items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
elif isinstance(v, collections.Sequence) and not isinstance(v, str):
    items.extend(sum((flatten(vv, new_key + sep + str(kk), sep).items() for kk, vv in enumerate(v)), []))
else:
    items.append((new_key, v))
```

Unpacking that:

```
flatten(vv, new_key + sep + str(kk), sep).items() for kk, vv in enumerate(v)
```

gets the flattened output for each item in the list, with the index used for the new *new* key. Then we combine all of these to get a list, and extend `items` with  that. (Or you could loop over each and extend `items` repeatedly... .)

Comment: Its giving me `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: `elif isinstance(v, collections.Sequence) and not isinstance(v,str):` - strings are also sequences- you need to exclude them