# Python - iterate and update a nested dictionary & lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion, graph

Having the following dict, where some of the values can be list of dictionaries:

```
{
  "A": [
    {
      "B": {
        "C": "D",
        "X": "CHNAGE ME"
      }
    },
    {
      "E": "F"
    }
  ],
  "G": {
    "Y": "CHANGE ME"
  }
}
```

I would like to recursively iterate over the items and change the pairs of key values where the value is "CHANGE ME", so the result would be:

```
{
  "A": [
    {
      "B": {
        "C": "D",
        "X.CHANGED": "CHANGED"
      }
    },
    {
      "E": "F"
    }
  ],
  "G": {
    "Y.CHANGED": "CHANGED"
  }
}
```

Solutions I've found were not handling a case where the value is a list, for example:

```
import collections
def nested_dict_iter(nested):
    for key, value in nested.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, collections.Mapping):
            for inner_key, inner_value in nested_dict_iter(value):
                yield inner_key, inner_value
        else:
            yield key, value
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Updating that involves replacing keys is usually more trouble than it's worth, jsut create a new data-structure.

Comment: You can use the logic used for flatten here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55294445/how-can-i-flatten-dict-containing-list-by-considering-its-index-as-key

Answer (score 12):

Using recursion

**Ex:**

```
def update(data):
    for k, v in data.copy().items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):     # For DICT
            data[k] = update(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):   # For LIST
            data[k] = [update(i) for i in v]
        elif v == 'CHANGE ME':      # Update Key-Value
            # data.pop(k)
            # OR
            del data[k]
            data[f"{k}.CHANGED"] = 'CHANGED'
    
    return data

print(update(data))
```

**Output:**

```
{
    'A':[{'B': {'C': 'D', 'X.CHANGED': 'CHANGED'}}, {'E': 'F'}], 
    'G':{'Y.CHANGED': 'CHANGED'}
 }
```

**Note**: I have not tested all corner cases

Comment: This did the trick for me. Thank you.

There is one update I would recommend: Beware of lists as they don't have ```data.copy.items()``` method. For lists you need to use ```enumerate(data.copy())```.

Comment: @Rakesh, can you suggest any solution for this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73069851/1138192

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I needed to replace key characters for storing in db. I also found it needed to handle case where array has non-dict elements (copy with fail on these types). Building on Rakesh's solution:

```
def filter_dict_keys(data):
    if isinstance(data, str) or isinstance(data, int):
        return data
    for k, v in data.copy().items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v = filter_dict_keys(v)
        if isinstance(v, list):
            v = [filter_dict_keys(i) for i in v]
        if '.' in k:
            del data[k]
            data[k.replace('.', ';')] = v
    return data
```

Example:

```
>>> a = {'1': '1', '2': ['2', '3', '4', '5.5', {'6.6': '6.6'}], '7': {'8': '8', '9': '9', '10': {'1.1': {'1.2': '1.3'}}}}
>>> filter_dict_keys(a)
{'1': '1', '2': ['2', '3', '4', '5.5', {'6;6': '6.6'}], '7': {'8': '8', '9': '9', '10': {'1;1': {'1;2': '1.3'}}}}
```