# Pytest : compare two json files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an API that creates a JSON file, like below:

```
"tesla_2.0": {
        "kind": "Auto",
        "tar_path": "/home/scripts/project_2/tesla_2.0.zip",
        "version": "2.0",
        "yaml_path": "/home/scripts/project_2/test.yaml",
        "name": "tesla"
    }
```

Since I'm reading it from a file, I use json.load() that will lose the order of the saved object unless I tell it to load into an OrderedDict().

is there a simple and efficient way to compare the to files ?

```
 def compare_json_files(file_1, file_2):
        if not os.path.isfile(file_1):
            raise FileNotFoundError("File not found: {}".format(file_1))
        if not os.path.isfile(file_2):
            raise FileNotFoundError("File not found: {}".format(file_2))
        with open(file_1, 'r') as f1:
            data_1 = json.loads(f1)
        with open(file_2, 'r') as f2:
            data_2 = json.loads(f2)
        comparison operation
```

Python version : 3.5.2

Comment: How exactly do you want to compare it? Why doesn't just `data_1 == data_2` work?

Comment: require literal, value-to-value equality between 2 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe you could check every keys and values. You should first check the set of keys are equal in both sides, then key by key comparison will make sense.

```py
assert(data_1.keys() == data_2.keys())
err_log = [['Err log:']] 
for k, v in data_1.items():
    try:
        assert(v == data_2[k])
    except:
        err_log.append(['Error catched for key=', k, ', data_1 value=', v, ', data_2 value=', data_2[k]])
[print(str(e)) for e in err_log]
```

#### Edit 3: Tested on very big dictionaries.

##### Best results are obtained with itemgetter of sorted list of keys for very large dictionaries.

##### Iterating through all keys of dictionaries is the worst. Iterating with ordered list of keys seems to perform slightly better.

Results:

- n = 100:

  - 4e-3 seconds
  - 3e-3 seconds
  - 1.5e-3 seconds
  - 1.9e-3 seconds
- n = 1,000,000:

  - 8.9 seconds
  - 9.2 seconds
  - 7.2 seconds
  - 6.9 seconds
- n = 10,000,000:

  - 143 seconds
  - 130 seconds
  - 115 seconds
  - 99 seconds

```py
from copy import deepcopy
from time import time
from operator import itemgetter

n = 10000000
v = {"stuff": "here", "and": "there"}
data_1 = {str(k): deepcopy(v) for k in range(0, n)}
data_2 = {str(k): deepcopy(v) for k in range(n-1, -1, -1)}

def get_time(f):
    def _(*args, **kwargs):
        t_0 = time()
        for x in range(10):
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        return time() - t_0
    return _

def with_dict_keys(d):
    return d.keys()

def with_sorted_dict_keys(d):
    return sorted(d.keys())

@get_time
def order_n_compare(key_func, d, d_):
    k_d, k_d_ = key_func(d), key_func(d_)
    assert(k_d == k_d_)
    for k in k_d:
        assert(d[k] == d_[k])


@get_time
def itemgetter_compare(key_func, d, d_):
    k_d, k_d_ = key_func(d), key_func(d_)
    assert(k_d == k_d_)
    assert(itemgetter(*k_d)(d) == itemgetter(*k_d)(d_))
```

###### Edit 0: added try & except block to print out where assertions are wrong

###### Edit 1: fixed minor bug

###### Edit 2: Check computation time: the `dictionnary.keys()` operation is irrelevant over iterating through all keys in `data_1.items()` because it grows order n. So it's not really necessary to optimize it.

- Note: If sorting `dict.keys()` is order(log(n)) then the operation time of getting `dict.keys()` seems to be order log(n) too.

Comment: Thats great, let me try and let you know :) thank you !

Comment: `data_1.keys()` and `data_2.keys()` also give ordered list

Comment: fixed a minor bug

Comment: Yea, I was about to share that :)

Comment: @HarshaBiyani I'm investigating the operation cost of dict.keys() vs set(dict)

Comment: @AlexandreMahdhaoui : you can try: `sortted(data_1.keys()) == sortted(data_2.keys()) `

Comment: @HarshaBiyani  : What if I dont care about the order of keys and values inside my nested dictionary , just wanted to check the data is equal.. How can I do that ?
It says assertion error because, nested keys are of different order.

Comment: @ChelMS in that case, we should 1st flatten the json, & compare

Comment: @ChelMS : you can use, accepted answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55294445/how-can-i-flatten-dict-containing-list-by-considering-its-index-as-key  to flatten the json, so everything comes in single level.